"Import could not be resolved from source" with docker setup in VSCode
I am writing a Python (Django) project that is being run in a docker container; nothing is run/interpreted on my local machine.  I'm getting this warning on all of my imports in VSCode: Import "django.test" could not be resolved from source.
I've seen a couple similar questions to this related to locally installed interpreters/venvs, however these don't seem to apply in my case, as I don't have a special interpreter on my machine -- everything runs in a docker container, my machine just edits source code, and never needs to run it.
Ideally, I'd like to resolve this warning in a way that doesn't cripple VSCode's ability to warn me about legitimate issues, and I'd prefer not to install anything on my host machine that isn't necessary.
Is there a way to use the context of my docker container for VSCode so that it can find these dependencies?  Is the easiest/most efficient option to just create a venv on my local machine and install my dependencies there purely for VSCode's peace of mind?  Are there any other options available to me (that aren't simply disabling this class of warning in settings)?

VS Code supports dev containers: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers

Software in a container intrinsically is isolated from the host; you need to jump through a lot of hoops to use a Python container to work on local code.  IME it's much easier to just install the tools you need for development on your host system, in between tools like pyenv and Hatch that can get a Python for you and MacOS and Linux systems generally coming with Python as part of the OS.

You can install Remote Development extension to use the Python environment from within your Docker container for linting and code analysis.

After installing the extension, you could create a .devcontainer folder in the root of your project and create a devcontainer.json file inside the folder:

{
  "name": "Django Project",
  "context": "..",
  "dockerFile": "path/to/your/Dockerfile",
  "settings": {
    "python.pythonPath": "/path/to/your/python/interpreter/in/container"
  },
  "extensions": [
    "ms-python.python",
    "ms-python.vscode-pylance"
  ],
  "postCreateCommand": "pip install -r requirements.txt"
}


Then you could use command Dev Containers: Reopen in Container to build your Docker container and open your project inside the container.


Will this work if I also have a separate container running Node for rendering my Frontend with React?  I am using docker compose to manage multiple containers (although only Python code is complaining about import issues).

This problem is somewhat different from the original problem, you can try to open a new issue, so that it is also convenient for future users who encounter similar problems to find out. If my answer solve your original issue, you could click "√" to mark it.

Fair enough.  I'll give this a shot, it sounds promising, just haven't had a chance to try it yet.
